# Partial Differential equation initial condition

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, nonlinear

For the equation $u=xu_{x} + yu_{y} + \dfrac{1}{2}(u_{x}^{2} + u_{y}^{2})$ find a solution with $u(x,0)= \dfrac{1}{2}(1-x^{2})$

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it looks like a homework question dump and does not explain how is this a Wolfram Mathematica Programming issue. @Jakoblibniz, your question may be [closed](https://goo.gl/jXYaiD) because it's not clear what you need. To avoid or revert the Hold you can [edit] your question to [improve it](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) and make it specific, well structured and easy to understand. Please don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your questions are and will be most welcomed. Learn about [good questions here](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3).

Comment: BTW, Welcome! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3). [Edit](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because homework questions need to show all the meaningful work done by the OP so far before asking a pertinent question. As noted above, that effort seems to be missing.

Answer (score 2):

I am just going to leave this here in case you genuinely could use a jumpstart for coding this in MMA. However, I have also voted to close the question as unsuitable for the site in its current form.

```
DSolve[
  {
    u[x, y] == x D[u[x, y], x] + y D[u[x, y], y] + 1/2 (D[u[x, y], x]^2 + D[u[x, y], y]^2),
    u[x, 0] == 1/2 (1 - x^2)
  },
  u[x, y], {x, y}
]

(* {{u[x, y] -> 1/2 (1 - x^2 + 2 y)}} *)
```